# Modiying SQL Server data format

Tags: sql-server, union, inner-join

I have data from surveys stored in a SQL Server database and I am using tableau to analyze it. One of Tableaus quirks is it needs the data in a certain format as this link shows

[Tableau data style](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/survey-data-grid-questions)

their method of using a union works however my data is spread over 100 questions some of which have 10 options. This creates a huge SQL `UNION` statement that would be nearly impossible to edit.

My plan was to perform the union with each question that needs to be altered and then inner join with the other data that doesn't need to be modified however the join results in just the first select statements fields being returned.

Here is the union statement for reference

```
 select
    [Survey].[SurveyId] AS [SurveyId],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[DisclosureResponsibility_Importance] AS  [importance],
    'Disclosure Responsibility' as [HCI_Importance]
FROM [Survey].[Survey] [Survey] 
INNER JOIN [Survey].[HumanCapital_Issues] [HumanCapital_Issues] ON ([survey].[SurveyId] = [HumanCapital_Issues].[SurveyId])

union

select
    [Survey].[SurveyId] AS [SurveyId],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[DevelopingSkills_Importance] AS  [importance],
    'Developing skills' as [HCI_Importance]
FROM [Survey].[Survey] [Survey]
INNER JOIN [Survey].[HumanCapital_Issues] [HumanCapital_Issues] ON ([Survey].[SurveyId] = [HumanCapital_Issues].[SurveyId])


SELECT [Survey].[SurveyId] AS [Survey_SurveyId],
    [Survey].[Year] AS [Year],
    [Survey].[FinancialInstitutionCode] AS [FinancialInstitutionCode],
    [Survey].[DeletionCode] AS [DeletionCode],
    [Survey].[SalaryOnly] AS [SalaryOnly],
    [FinancialInstitution].[FinancialInstitutionCode] AS [FinancialInstitution_FinancialInstitutionCode],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Name] AS [Name],
    [FinancialInstitution].[FDIC] AS [FDIC],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Address_Street1] AS [Address_Street1],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Address_Street2] AS [Address_Street2],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Address_City] AS [Address_City],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Address_State] AS [Address_State],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Address_Zip] AS [Address_Zip],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Address_County] AS [Address_County],
    [FinancialInstitution].[ParentCompany] AS [ParentCompany],
    [FinancialInstitution].[FDICBHC] AS [FDICBHC],
    [FinancialInstitution].[OwnershipStructureCode] AS [OwnershipStructureCode],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Employees_FullTimeEquivalent] AS [Employees_FullTimeEquivalent],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Employees_FullTime] AS [Employees_FullTime],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Employees_PartTime] AS [Employees_PartTime],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Branches_FullService] AS [Branches_FullService],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Branches_InStore] AS [Branches_InStore],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Brances_LimitedService] AS [Brances_LimitedService],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Headquarters_Population] AS [Headquarters_Population],
    [FinancialInstitution].[LargestCity_Population] AS [LargestCity_Population],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Assets] AS [Assets],
    [FinancialInstitution].[Deposits] AS [Deposits],
    [FinancialInstitution].[TARP_Participated] AS [TARP_Participated],
    [FinancialInstitution].[TARP_CausedConcern] AS [TARP_CausedConcern],
    [FinancialInstitution].[TARP_RequiredChanges] AS [TARP_RequiredChanges],
    [FinancialInstitution].[RegionCode] AS [RegionCode],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[SurveyId] AS [HumanCapital_Issues_SurveyId],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[DisclosureResponsibility_Concern] AS [DisclosureResponsibility_Concern],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[DevelopingSkills_Concern] AS [DevelopingSkills_Concern],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[MotivatingPerformance_Concern] AS [MotivatingPerformance_Concern],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[Reorganizations_Concern] AS [Reorganizations_Concern],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[Hiring_Concern] AS [Hiring_Concern],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[Retention_Concern] AS [Retention_Concern],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[ContainingCosts_Concern] AS [ContainingCosts_Concern],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[ManagingRetirements_Concern] AS [ManagingRetirements_Concern],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[SalesCulture_Concern] AS [SalesCulture_Concern],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[DevelopingLeaders_Concern] AS [DevelopingLeaders_Concern],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[Other_Description] AS [Other_Description],
    [HumanCapital_Issues].[Other_Concern] AS [Other_Concern]
FROM 
    [Survey].[Survey] [Survey]
INNER JOIN 
    [Profile].[FinancialInstitution] [FinancialInstitution] ON ([Survey].[SurveyId] = [FinancialInstitution].[FinancialInstitutionCode])
INNER JOIN 
    [Survey].[HumanCapital_Issues] [HumanCapital_Issues] ON ([Survey].[SurveyId] = [HumanCapital_Issues].[SurveyId])
```

Is there an "easy way" to perform a union then join it with another select statement?

Comment: It's not necessary to constantly name columns back to their old names: "`[HumanCapital_Issues].[Hiring_Concern] AS [Hiring_Concern]`". It's already called `Hiring_Concern`.

Comment: Do the union first and then do the joins on the result.

Comment: What columns would you use in the join? What would connect one row from altered questions to a row from unaltered questions? SurveyId?

Answer (score 0):

If I finally understood the problem, you want to join single query getting most of the data and union query getting specific sections to their places. Hopefully SurveyID is connecting element. Use your existing queries as derived tables:

```
select *
  from
  (
     { union query here }
  ) q1
 inner join
  (
     { query with all the data here }
  ) q2
    on q1.SurveyID = q2.SurveyID
```